# Tapku Library: TKCalendarDayTimelineView (iPhone)

Tags: xcode, ios6, tapku

Good morning (afternoon, evening).
I'm using TKCalendarMonthView and TKCalendarDayTimelineView in my application.
There weren't any problems with the first one (I used http://developinginthedark.com/posts/iphone-tapku-calendar-markers).
I have a problem with TKCalendarDayTimelineView. There are no examples on the Internet.

I initialize the TKCalendarDayTimelineView

```
(.h):

#import "TKCalendarMonthView.h"
#import "TKCalendarDayTimelineView.h"

@interface BDThirdViewController : UIViewController <TKCalendarMonthViewDelegate,      TKCalendarMonthViewDataSource, TKCalendarDayTimelineViewDelegate> {
    TKCalendarMonthView *calendarMonth;
    TKCalendarDayTimelineView *calendarDay;
    .......
}


(.m):
calendarDay = [[TKCalendarDayTimelineView alloc] init];
calendarDay.delegate = self;
calendarDay.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300);
```

and get:
(image) http://index01d.com/ci2m/w85xvg

Do you have any examples of using the TKCalendarDayTimelineView? Help me please, i'm new to ios development.

Thanks in advance